# Companions in Novigrad's Arena?

Tags: the-witcher-3

During the "Finding Whoreson Junior" quest you can fight in the arena.

You have to fight several opponents but after you injure them half-way they yield and ask for mercy (at least few of the first ones), you can accept or just kill them as crowd wants it.

I managed to "save" the first one and he helped me fight in the rest of the fights, but sadly died in the process.

Anyone managed to "save" the second wave as well (brothers from Skellige I think) and keep them alive until the end?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can "save" the first challenger is because he yields, and begs for mercy (you can let him live by talking to him).
The brothers from Skellige don't stop and let you choose to save them, so you cannot have them become allies in the same way.

Comment: Though I guess it's possible that I just killed them too quickly.

Comment: Yeah sorry, for not pointing out that you have to interact with first opponent to "save" him.
Too bad that brothers can't help, it would make interesting output.

Comment: Yeah. I think they got dismembered for me, which is why I doubt their survival. Seems like they wouldn't, if they could, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I saved the man, and we fought together all the way to end. Blood, sweat, and tears carried us through until that bastard Igor sent his men down to kill us. I nearly lost my new friend as a halberd took a wide swing towards our hips but a quick roll and slice across his back made short work of our foe. Then, my dear friend, who apparently father's several children, sheathed his sword and walked back to the arena. I could not get him to leave. All's well that ends well I suppose...